# Getting Performance Stats out of JOGL

Tags: performance, opengl, jogl

I would have thought this would be a simple one, so I've searched around a bit, but I can't find it.

Is there a way to get stats like **triangles drawn per second** from JOGL? I know I can get the FPS from the animator, but some of the deeper stats would be nice. I'm mostly after the triangles per second, but texture fill rate and anything else available would be interesting too.

Thanks.

Comment: No sure if this would be better on gamedev? I'll leave it up here for a bit, then move over there if I don't get a bite, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you can use the animator to get fps statistics.

Or you can use [GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/pipeline_statistics_query.txt) that introduces new query types that allow applications to get statistics information about different parts of the pipeline:

- number of vertices and primitives issued to the GL;
- number of times a vertex shader, tessellation evaluation shader, geometry shader, fragment shader, and compute shader was invoked;
- number of patches processed by the tessellation control shader stage;
- number of primitives emitted by a geometry shader;
- number of primitives that entered the primitive clipping stage;

You can take inspiration from this [sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_450/Gl_450_query_statistics_arb.java).

So, if you want to get the number of triangles rendered per second on your application, start the [query](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_450/Gl_450_query_statistics_arb.java#L327) and after one second [terminate it](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_450/Gl_450_query_statistics_arb.java#L343), [collect](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_450/Gl_450_query_statistics_arb.java#L359) the result and divide by 3